# phpmyadmin error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1"

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1062

I dropped all tables from a database then restore(import) a backup. Afterwards I am getting `error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1`.

Should i repeat the process. Or something else? Why this error is coming?

Comment: You will need to remove the duplicate entry from your database (yes from the backup SQL).

Comment: Not true, this is a problem with the way it interprets the imported SQL and you should not remove anything.

Answer (score 7):

When you export your sql from php admin

[image]

Select "custom" as export method"

[image]

then, instead of 'insert', choose "update"

This will perform update-statements and prevent duplicated inserts.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary, this fixed it for me. I was struggling with it for over a day!

Answer (score 5):

This indicates that you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY index on a table, and there is a duplicate value on one of the values that will be inserted into one of these indexes.

You'll need to look at which particular operation caused this error to find out which table and which row it was trying to write.  Hopefully, phpMyAdmin *should* tell you which row of data caused the problem, shouldn't it?

One guess is that you're importing data that duplicates some data already in a table, ie you may not have removed the existing data like you thought you had.  But it could be any number of things.

Comment: i want to remove all previous tables from database and want to import from another sql file.

Comment: I selected all tables then dropped. Is it not enough?

Comment: This happened to me as well once, I too dropped the tables and tried  importing the csv, and ended up in this error. After reading this post of @thomasrutter, I checked my table data and saw that for some reason the csv headers alone got inserted as one record and that caused unique constraint violation next time I tried to import the csv data. I deleted all records and again tried, and yup it worked!

Comment: Indeed, I've had that happen too. Can also happen if you have cruft (ie mostly blank lines with just notes or random characters in them) at the bottom of the CSV

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds if it, the dump has a duplicate entry inside the queries it holds.

Although this shouldn't happen, it happened to me in the past.
In order to solve this, I would advise two options:

1. Manually remove the `ADD UNIQUE INDEX` and/or `PRIMARY KEY` at the start of each table dump. Then create a same structure table, add the missing index, and `INSERT IGNORE INTO new_tbl (SELECT * FROM tbl)`
2. Adding `INSERT IGNORE` for the insert statement in the log

Answer (score -1):

To fix this, when you want to export DB you can try to untick "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values" under "Format-Specific Options:" , see image below :

[image]